# Want to change prefix characters, then add suffixed characters in changed string

Tags: string, bash, perl, sed, text-processing

I want to create a poor-man's replace for HTML-izing a string text.

A sample text is:

```
THIS IS A TEST.@@01 THIS IS ANOTHER TEST.@@02
```

What I have been using (which works for both Mac and LINUX) is this:

```
echo "THIS IS A TEST.@@01 THIS IS ANOTHER TEST.@@02" | perl -p -e "s|\@\@|\[\&\#10070\;301|g"
```

I get this:

```
THIS IS A TEST.[&#10070;30101 THIS IS ANOTHER TEST.[&#10070;30102
```

What I'd like is this:

```
THIS IS A TEST.[&#10070;30101] THIS IS ANOTHER TEST.[&#10070;30102]`
```

(with the `]` added at the end of each prefixed number)

The numbers will always be 2-digits in length, so that makes things slightly easier.  But, I am trying to create a HTML-ized string from regular text using this technique. How do I do that using the 'perl' command as an alternative for 'sed'?

Answer (score 2):

Use a capture group to capture the number after `@@`, and a back-reference in the replacement text to insert it between the prefix and suffix that you're adding.

```
echo "THIS IS A TEST.@@01 THIS IS ANOTHER TEST.@@02" | sed -E 's/@@([0-9]+)/[\&#10070;301\1]/g'
```

Answer (score 2):

What I would do, using [*capture group*](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Capture-groups):

```
echo "THIS IS A TEST.@@01 THIS IS ANOTHER TEST.@@02" |
    perl -pe 's/@@(\d+)/[&#10070;301$1]/g'
```

```
THIS IS A TEST.[&#10070;30101] THIS IS ANOTHER TEST.[&#10070;30102]
```

Comment: In general you will want to escape `@` inside an interpolated string. The `s/@@...` works (I think!) because there is no punctuation variable `@@`. Or, you could prevent interpolation in the substitution by spelling it `s'@@(\d+)'[&#10070;301$1]'g`.

Comment: @user20284150 There is a punctuation var `@@` (because there is a punctuation var `$@`). While regex literals are similar to double-quoted string literals, they don't interpolate arrays -- it wouldn't be useful -- so there's no need to escape `@`.

Comment: @user20284150 Your alternative solution doesn't work because the single quotes also prevent `$1` from being interpolated.

Comment: Right on both counts, though `@@` is not documented in perlvar. My bad. I believe the correct single-quote expression is `s'@@(\d+)'[&#10070;301\1]'g`.

Answer (score 1):

You may just use `sed`:

```bash
echo "THIS IS A TEST.@@01 THIS IS ANOTHER TEST.@@02" |
  sed -E 's/@@([0-9]{2})/[\&#10070;301\1]/g' 

THIS IS A TEST.[&#10070;30101] THIS IS ANOTHER TEST.[&#10070;30102]
```

Here `([0-9]{2})` matches 2 digits and captures in group #1. We use back-reference `\1` in replacement to be able to place `]` after `@@` and 2 digits.

Comment: Indeed. In Perl it's normal to escape all punctuation characters, to future-proof in case they get turned into regexp operators.